# JWKS key info not found at well-known endpoint

Tags: java, jwt, auth0, jwk

My Spring Boot app is attempting to use `Auth0` to validate a JWT it receives. My problem is the JWKS endpoint I have to connect to provides all of key information at the root of the URL, versus the well-known endpoint. My code snippet looks like so:

```
DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(jwt);
JwkProvider provider = new UrlJwkProvider(new URL(configProperties.getKeyUrl()), 5000, 2000);
Jwk jwk = provider.get(jwt.getKeyId());
```

Is there a way to adapt `JwkProvider` to look at a different URL? The javadoc seems to say `/.well-known...` is going to be appended no matter what I do. Perhaps there's another library I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally decided the simplest thing to do was to edit the source from `UrlJwkProvider` myself. I created a new class and removed the code that appends the well known URL. Easy-peasy.